# Building a map of leaf - list of ancestors with pairs (parent - child)

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

I have a tree structure I need to represent in the form of a map, the key being the leaf and the value the list of the leaf's ancestors (the order of ancestors is not important).

So for example, a tree like this :

```
      1
     / \
    2   3
   / \
  4   5
 /
6
```

would end up like this :

```
6 -> [4, 2, 1]
5 -> [2, 1]
3 -> [1]
```

To build this map, I am given a list of pairs (parent, child).

For the example tree, I would be given, in no particular order, this :

```
1, 2
1, 3
2, 4
2, 5
4, 6
```

An execution example to better understand :

At first, the map is empty. I am given 2, 4.

The map contains 4 -> [2]. I am given 2, 5.

The map contains 4 -> [2], 5 -> [2]. I am given 4, 6.

The map contains 6 -> [4, 2], 5 -> [2]. I am given 1, 3.

The map contains 6 -> [4, 2], 5 -> [2], 3 -> [1]. I am given 1, 2.

The map contains 6 -> [4, 2, 1], 5 -> [2, 1], 3 -> [1].

I have come up with something, but it feels bloated and difficult to understand.
It's also wrong with some specific order of inputs :

```
1, 3
4, 6
1, 2
2, 4
2, 5
```

yields

```
6 -> [4, 2, 1]
5 -> [4, 2, 1]
3 -> [1]
```

The code :

```
updateMap(long parent, long child) {
    if (map.isEmpty()) {
        map.put(child, Sets.newHashSet(parent));
    } else {
        Set<Long> flattenedValues = new HashSet<Long>();
        for (Set<Long> set : map.values()) {
            flattenedValues.addAll(set);
        }
        if (flattenedValues.contains(child)) {
            for (Long key : getKeysByValue(map, child)) {
                map.get(key).add(parent);
            }
            if (map.containsKey(parent)) {
                for (Long key : getKeysByValue(map, parent)) {
                    Set<Long> toAdd = new HashSet<Long>();
                    toAdd.add(parent);
                    toAdd.addAll(map.remove(parent));
                    map.get(key).addAll(toAdd);
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (map.containsKey(parent)) {
                map.put(child, Sets.newHashSet(parent));
                map.get(child).addAll(
                        map.remove(parent));
            } else {
                map.put(child, Sets.newHashSet(parent));
                for (Long key : getKeysByValue(map, parent)) {
                    map.get(child).addAll(map.get(key));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am sure there is a better way to do what I want, can you help me ? Thanks !

Comment: are you allowed to use additional data strucutures to read in the tree our just the map. Moreover do you read in the pairs once or is data added at runtime

Comment: I have a very simple array based solution.

Comment: @PKuhn : It's not clear in the question, but I don't have a tree to read : I only have the pairs to work with. The tree is the result of the process, in the form of a map. Data is added at runtime.

Comment: @l0r3nz4cc10 Feel free for any queries.

Answer (score 1):

This can be very easily solved using arrays.There will be 2 arrays that will be very useful.

**isLeaf**:This array will store boolean values and will tell whether a node is leaf or not. Initially all values are true.

Whenever a pair is entered the value for the first element is set to false as it has a child.

**parent**:This array will store values for parent of a node.Initially all values are set to -1 and whenever a pair is entered,then parent value for the second element of the pair is set to first element.

**Basic Idea**:The idea to solve this problem is very simple and elegant.

Basically we iterate through the nodes and for all nodes that are leaf we list their ancestors using the parent array **and the terminating condition is also very simple because we will stop only when we reach the root and for root only parent is set to -1**

```
import java.util.*;
class Tree
{
 public static void main(String []args)
 {
     int n,i,p,j,c,pairs;
     Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("enter the number of elements in tree");
     n=sc.nextInt();
     boolean []isLeaf=new boolean[n];
     int []parent=new int[n];     
     for(i=0;i<n;++i)
     {
          isLeaf[i]=true;
          parent[i]=-1;
     }
     System.out.println("Enter the number of  pairs");
     pairs=sc.nextInt();
     System.out.println("now enter pairs like 1 2(separate them by space)");
     for(i=0;i<pairs;++i)
     {
         p=sc.nextInt();
         c=sc.nextInt();
         isLeaf[p-1]=false;
         parent[c-1]=p-1;
     }     
     for(i=0;i<n;++i)
      if(isLeaf[i])
      {
          j=i;
          System.out.println("\nthe ancestors of "+(i+1)+" are");
          while(parent[j]!=-1)
           {System.out.print((parent[j]+1)+" ");j=parent[j];}
      }
 }
}
```

Comment: You should explain your answer. Just pasting a blob of code does NOTHING to help the OP understand his problem or your solution. This isn't a coding service, it's a place to get help and explanations.

Comment: @leigero The answer is so simple that its self explanatory,however if you insist then I will.

Comment: If it were simple and self explanatory to the OP he wouldn't be here asking for help. Try to keep that in mind. Not everybody (this person or future viewers of this question) is on the same skill level.

Comment: @leigero Hope it satisfies you.Thank you for making me improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

After having a close look at your code, I found the problem: You cannot add a mapping, where the parent node is an inner node. To do so, you would need to add the parents of the parent as parents of the child. However, you do not hold any information about the parents of inner nodes.

The portion of your code which handles this case is the most indented else branch:

```
        } else {
            map.put(child, Sets.newHashSet(parent));
            for (Long key : getKeysByValue(map, parent)) {
                map.get(child).addAll(map.get(key));
            }
        }
```

Instead of the parents of the inner node, you add the parents of the leafs of the inner node. We can see, that this is a difference in your example. You want to add the pair (2, 5), so you need to add the parents of the inner node 2 to the set of parents of the child node 5. The correct set to add would be {1}. However, you ask the leafs of the inner node 2, which is {6} for their parents, which are {1, 2, 4}.

I am not sure, whether this is the only problem, though.

---

I corrected your code by adding in a second map `nodeToParentsMap`, which holds the set of parents nodes also for inner nodes. The `leafMap` holds the same data, but only for the leaf nodes. Additionally, the `rootNodes` set helps to identify, whether a node is a root node. My code also handles the case, where you try to set the parent for a node that already has a parent. It throws a `RuntimeException` in that case. If you have any questions about the code, don't hesitate to ask.

The code:

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;

public class TreeExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TreeExample().run();
    }

    private Map<Long, Set<Long>> leafMap = new HashMap<Long, Set<Long>>();
    private Map<Long, Set<Long>> nodeToParentsMap = new HashMap<Long, Set<Long>>();
    private Set<Long> rootNodes = new HashSet<Long>();

    public void run() {
        print();
        add(1, 3);
        print();
        add(4, 6);
        print();
        add(1, 2);
        print();
        add(2, 4);
        print();
        add(2, 5);
        print();
    }

    private void add(long parent, long child) {
        System.out.println("adding: " + parent + " => " + child);
        addEntry(parent, child);
    }

    private void print() {
        System.out.println("leafMap: " + leafMap);
        System.out.println("nodeToParentsMap: " + nodeToParentsMap);
        System.out.println("rootNodes: " + rootNodes);
        System.out.println();
    }

    private void addEntry(long parent, long child) {
        if (isRootNode(child)) {
            simpleAddEntry(parent, child);
            rootNodes.remove(child);
            addParentsToAllChildren(child);
        } else if (isKnownNode(child)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("this child already has a parent");
        } else { // child is not in tree
            simpleAddEntry(parent, child);
            leafMap.put(child, nodeToParentsMap.get(child));
        }
    }

    private void simpleAddEntry(long parent, long child) {
        if (isRootNode(parent)) {
            // nothing special to do
        } else if (isLeafNode(parent)) {
            addParents(nodeToParentsMap.get(parent), child);
            leafMap.remove(parent);
        } else if (isKnownNode(parent)) {
            addParents(nodeToParentsMap.get(parent), child);
        } else { // parent is not in tree
            rootNodes.add(parent);
        }
        addParents(newHashSet(parent), child);
    }

    private void addParentsToAllChildren(long node) {
        Set<Long> parentsToAdd = nodeToParentsMap.get(node);
        for (Entry<Long, Set<Long>> entry : nodeToParentsMap.entrySet()) {
            Set<Long> currentParents = entry.getValue();
            if (currentParents.contains(node)) {
                currentParents.addAll(parentsToAdd);
            }
        }
    }

    private void addParents(Set<Long> parents, long child) {
        if (!nodeToParentsMap.containsKey(child)) {
            nodeToParentsMap.put(child, parents);
        } else {
            nodeToParentsMap.get(child).addAll(parents);
        }
    }

    private boolean isRootNode(long node) {
        return rootNodes.contains(node);
    }

    private boolean isLeafNode(long node) {
        return leafMap.containsKey(node);
    }

    private boolean isKnownNode(long node) {
        return nodeToParentsMap.containsKey(node);
    }

    private Set<Long> newHashSet(long... values) {
        Set<Long> result = new HashSet<Long>();
        for (long value : values) {
            result.add(value);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

The output:

```
leafMap: {}
nodeToParentsMap: {}
rootNodes: []

adding: 1 => 3
leafMap: {3=[1]}
nodeToParentsMap: {3=[1]}
rootNodes: [1]

adding: 4 => 6
leafMap: {3=[1], 6=[4]}
nodeToParentsMap: {3=[1], 6=[4]}
rootNodes: [1, 4]

adding: 1 => 2
leafMap: {2=[1], 3=[1], 6=[4]}
nodeToParentsMap: {2=[1], 3=[1], 6=[4]}
rootNodes: [1, 4]

adding: 2 => 4
leafMap: {3=[1], 6=[1, 2, 4]}
nodeToParentsMap: {2=[1, 2], 3=[1], 4=[1, 2], 6=[1, 2, 4]}
rootNodes: [1]

adding: 2 => 5
leafMap: {3=[1], 5=[1, 2], 6=[1, 2, 4]}
nodeToParentsMap: {2=[1, 2], 3=[1], 4=[1, 2], 5=[1, 2], 6=[1, 2, 4]}
rootNodes: [1]
```